# Drupal 8 white page while attempting to install JSON API and supporting modules

Tags: drupal-8, json-api

Drupal 8 white page while attempting to install JSON API and supporting modules. My Drupal 8 is already in using REST API module, which was working fine. I was trying to use the JSON API module.

Is there any way that I can get back to the previous state. My Drupal 8 is in Godaddy hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I sort it out running update.php file